# Adding a minute to time extracted from a command's output

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I'm making a script which checks the health of my server at home.

```
smartctl -t short /dev/sda | awk '/Please wait/ {print $3}'
```

This command shows how long it takes before the SmartCTL finish testing. 
But just to be sure, I want to add a command sleep, with the output of that command plus 1 minute, to make sure it's really finished.

Could someone help me out?

Comment: Please show what the output looks like and what you want it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could capture the output of your command pipeline and use it as an argument to `sleep`:

```
sleep_time=$(smartctl -t short /dev/sda | awk '/Please wait/ {print $3}')
# add logic to check if sleep_time is a number etc.
if [[ $sleep_time ]]; then
  sleep $((sleep_time + 60)) # assuming smartctl prints the wait value in seconds
else
  # there was no sleep time extracted from smartctl - add appropriate logic to handle that situation
fi
```

Comment: Hmm, I didn't think of adding the minute in the sleep command, I was trying to add it to the variable of the output of the SmartCTL command!
Thanks a lot, that will help me out!!

Answer (score 1):

```
sleep $((60+60*$(($(smartctl -t short /dev/sda|awk '/Please wait/ {print $3}')))))
```

seems to be what you are looking for.

- `sleep` defaults to arg in seconds.
- enclosing `$(smartctl ...)` in extra `$((...))` evaluates to zero if the subshell does not output an integer for some reason, and prevents the outermost evaluation to fail with a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks, didn't think of adding the extra minute in the sleep command, I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

```
wait=`(smartctl -t short /dev/sda | awk '/Please wait/ {print $3}'` # minutes
sleep $(($wait + 1))m
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't think of adding the extra minute in the sleep command, I'll give it a try!